# TSQL, counting coherent days of holiday

Tags: t-sql, count

I hope someone can help me on this one. :-)

I wish to count coherent periods of holiday to see if anyone had coherent holiday more than three days in a row. In other words it is not enough to count the number of days overall. The days have to be coherent. In the example of my data below I have illustrated three people with each their own days of holiday. Person 1234 has two periods of two days of holiday in a row, so this person has no periods above three days since there is a day in between two periods (the 3rd). Person 1235 and 1236 each have one period above three days. Time of day in the timestamps has no relevance, so data can be formatted as just date.

What I have:

| ID | Start |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1234 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 1234 | 2022-01-04 06:50:00 |
| 1234 | 2022-01-05 06:50:00 |
| 1235 | 2022-01-04 06:50:00 |
| 1235 | 2022-01-05 06:50:00 |
| 1235 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 |
| 1236 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1236 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 1236 | 2022-01-03 06:50:00 |
| 1236 | 2022-01-04 06:50:00 |
| 1236 | 2022-01-05 06:50:00 |
| 1236 | 2022-01-08 00:00:00 |

What I hope to get:

| ID | N holidays > 3 days |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 |
| 1235 | 1 |
| 1236 | 1 |

Anyways, any help will be appreciated!

Kind regards,

Jacob

Comment: How did the 1234 have holidays from 2022-01-05 06:50:00 to 2022-01-03, shouldn't it be from 03 to the 05th?

Comment: How come some start dates are greater than end dates?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gaps and islands" problem. You need to first group the data into "islands", which in your case is groups of consecutive holidays. Then summarize them in your final result set

Side note: your question requests greater than 3 days, but your expected output uses greater than or equal to 3 so I used that instead.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Holiday;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ConsecutiveHoliday
CREATE TABLE #Holiday (ID INT,StartDateTime DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Holiday
VALUES (1234,'2022-01-01 00:00:00')
,(1234,'2022-01-02 00:00:00')
,(1234,'2022-01-04 06:50:00')
,(1234,'2022-01-05 06:50:00')
,(1235,'2022-01-04 06:50:00')
,(1235,'2022-01-05 06:50:00')
,(1235,'2022-01-06 00:00:00')
,(1236,'2022-01-01 00:00:00')
,(1236,'2022-01-02 00:00:00')
,(1236,'2022-01-03 06:50:00')
,(1236,'2022-01-04 06:50:00')
,(1236,'2022-01-05 06:50:00')
,(1236,'2022-01-08 00:00:00');

WITH cte_Previous AS (
    SELECT A.ID,B.StartDate
        ,IsHolidayConsecutive = CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,-1,StartDate) /*Current day minus 1*/ = LAG(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate) /*Previous holiday date*/  
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END 
    FROM #Holiday AS A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT StartDate = CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE)) AS B
),
cte_Groups AS (
    SELECT *,GroupID = SUM(IsHolidayConsecutive) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate)
    FROM cte_Previous
)
/*Groups of holidays taken consecutively*/
SELECT ID
    ,StartDate = MIN(StartDate)
    ,EndDate = MAX(StartDate)
    ,NumOfDays = COUNT(*)
INTO #ConsecutiveHoliday
FROM cte_Groups
GROUP BY ID,GroupID
ORDER BY ID,StartDate

/*See list of consecutive holidays taken*/
SELECT *
FROM #ConsecutiveHoliday

/*Formatted result*/
SELECT ID
    ,[N holidays >= 3 days] = COUNT(CASE WHEN NumOfDays >= 3 THEN 1 END)
FROM #ConsecutiveHoliday
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is very helpful! Have a nice day! :-)

Comment: My pleasure! If this answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted so others know your question has been answered

Comment: I don't have an "accepted" button, presumably because I am a new user. When I upvote I get "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."